# Import custom taglib

Tags: java, jsp, url, import, taglib

We usually give reference to external taglib as `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>`

Can we define our custom taglib and `uri` in our jsp as below?

`<%@ taglib uri="com.mycompany.taglib" prefix="custom"%>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we define our custom taglib?

### Yes

What you have to do is create a tag handler class and tld file then import that tld file in your jsp page as

```
<%@taglib prefix="myCustomTag" tagdir="/WEB-INF/myCustomerTag.tld"%>
```

---

Useful links:

- [Create custom taglib - IBM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.webtoolscore.doc/topics/tcreatetag.html)
- [Tutorial: Create JSP custom tag library](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/12/tutorial-create-custom-tag-library-taglib-in-jsp.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one cane define custom tags. Take a look at this [Java EE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro9.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to to have tablib.tld file with your tags definitions and the taglib section with in web.xml